# Céline dit-il « babillons » ou « habillons » dans sa préface de Guignol's Band I, et finalement qu'est-ce qui « vole » et comment ?

Tags: sens, littérature

Le temps est venu de comprendre enfin ce que [Céline](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis-Ferdinand_C%C3%A9line) a écrit dans sa préface de *Guignol's Band I* :

> [...]
> À vous de comprendre ! Émouvez-vous ! « C'est que des bagarres tous
> vos chapitres » ! Quelle objection ! Quelle tourterie ! Ah ! attention
>  ! La niaise ! En botte ! Volent [**babillons/habillons**] ! Émouvez-vous bon Dieu !
> Ratata ! Sautez ! Vibrochez ! Éclatez dans vos carapaces !
> fouillez-vous crabes ! Éventrez ! Trouvez la palpite nom de foutre ! La
> fête est là ! Enfin ! Quelque chose ! Réveil ! Allez salut ! Robots la
> crotte ! Merde ! Transposez ou c'est la mort !
> [...]

Est-ce *babillons* ou *habillons* ? Anciennement, on trouve *babillons*. Si on a remplacé par *habillons*, est-ce que ça vient avec une explication de l'éditeur ou quoi que ce soit du genre ? L'auteur a dit que *volent* quoi au juste et qu'est-ce que ça signifie ?

Answer (score 2):

La réponse doit se trouver dans [l'édition de 1988](http://www.la-pleiade.fr/Catalogue/GALLIMARD/Bibliotheque-de-la-Pleiade/Romans12) de la Pléiade regroupant *Casse-pipe* et *Guignol's band* puisqu'elle s'appuie sur une relecture des manuscrits originaux de Céline retrouvés dans un coffre 30 ans après y avoir été déposés par leur auteur.

En attendant, je vote (quand même) pour ***Volent babillons !*** pour le jeu de mot et de lettres avec ***Volent papillons !***...

*Babillons* peut être interprété comme suit :

- babillonages : babillages, bavardages.
- babilloneurs : ceux qui babillent.
- variante de [barbillons](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/barbillon) : proxénètes.

*[Babillon](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/276015/meaning-of-players-and-port-of-a-bitt/276142#276142)* existe bien comme vieux mot français mais ne peut pas avoir de lien avec ce qu'a écrit Céline.

Comment: Non, avec un *b* au lieu d'un *h*, c'est ***Volent bavardages !*** … babiller : https://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/babille s'ajoute donc ici une ironie infantilisante.

Comment: @Personne Pourquoi le "non" ? Je comprends *babillons* comme ***babillonages*** (babillages, bavardages), ***babilloneurs*** (ceux qui babillent) ou une variante de ***barbillons*** (proxénètes).

Comment: Non aux *papillons* … et aux *proxénètes* dans le sens où leur baratin soumet leurs victimes, peut-être, mais mettre des ailes d'ange pour transformer les maquereaux en poissons volants ne correspond pas au contexte. Céline maîtrisant l'argot, langue vécue par la majorité de ses patients à l'encontre de tout académisme, aurait "manuscrit" le *r*.

Comment: Votre discussion a déclenché mon souvenir de [_Pépin la bulle_](https://youtu.be/RFOf6X4IWJk?t=25) : bulle, envole-toi !

Comment: @Personne _Babillons_ comme terme de marine, un truc qui serait d'un côté du pont, et dans lequel passerait un cordage ou un truc du genre, un espèce d'oeillet ?

Comment: @ZéhontéeBonteuse Faut croire que c'est quelque chose comme ça. J'ai posé la question [sur ELL et je me suis pris un -1](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/276015/meaning-of-players-and-port-of-a-bitt/276019#276019), les ingrats... Ma réputation en a pris un sacré coup ;-) et en plus, je ne sais toujours pas vraiment ce que sont ces *players*.

Comment: *Babillons* inconnu dans la marine hexagonale, mais peut faire partie du patois régional utilisé par les charpentiers de marine locaux, et donc inconnu de Céline ; *émerillon* fait partie de l'accastillage.  *Ba**r**billons  d'un poisson* : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/barbillon/substantif

Comment: @Personne, À priori, c'était une fausse piste. Les players seraient des parties métalliques mobiles du mors d'un cheval. C'est un peu ce que je soupçonnais et Zéhontée a trouvé une définition qui va bien dans l'OED http://archive.org/stream/oed07arch#page/978/mode/1up

Comment: @Personne Il ne faut négliger aucune piste même les impasses... et le Cotgrave n'est pas qu'un "dico anglais", c'est quand même un monument sur le français de l'époque.

Comment: @Personne Ces *players* sont à priori des "jouets" (pour occuper la langue et la machoire du cheval et le faire saliver) attachés à la partie interne (*port*) du mors (*bit*) d'un cheval.

Comment: … équipé ainsi, le cheval *babille* !

Comment: @Personne La boucle est bouclée !

Comment: J'ai posté une réponse sur ELL C'était intéressant mais on est bien loin de Céline... Je l'ajoute quand même.

Comment: Un truc comme un véhicule... une question.

Comment: @escarlateadamantine "babillon" apparaît dans le Dictionnaire du Moyen Français comme synonyme de "bavard, sot, nigaud" : https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dmf/babillon